# Rails 3 - link_to() - need multiple text segments with separate HTML/CSS classes in a single link

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I'm creating a "compound" link using `link_to`.  The link text has a prefix portion formatted in one CSS style, and a root portion formatted in a different CSS style.  For example:

**pre***process*

I've been able to crudely achieve this with two, back-to-back `link_to` statements:

```
<div class="dual-format-link">
    <%= link_to 'pre', compound_path, :class => "prefix-style" %><%= link_to 'process', compound_path, :class => "root-style" %>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the roll-over affect clearly shows that these are two different links, just arranged side-by-side.  The fact that it is not a single, unified link causes user confusion.

I tried putting HTML in `link_to`'s first argument but it is displayed as raw HTML.

Is there a way to have `link_to` do this?  Are there alternatives to `link_to` that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Rails that the html is okay to render as html instead of escaped plain text by using `html_safe`:

```
<div class="dual-format-link">
    <%= link_to '<span class="prefix-style">pre</span><span class="root-style">process</span>'.html_safe, compound_path %>
</div>
```

See http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ for more information.